# What does "ActionBar not available for TabGroup" mean?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

My Android app has been working fine with Titanium SDK 3.5.2 but I tried to update it to 5.2.0.GA. But I get the error `[ERROR] TabGroupProxy: (main) [517,517] ActionBar not available for TabGroup`. What does that mean?

The app starts up but the tabs never appear and the screen is just all grey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g2o's answer gave me a directional clue and I figured that it was because I had the following in my tiapp.xml file:

```
<navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
```

I guess in with newer versions it's not allowed to hide the navbar/ActionBar. When I set this to false the error disappeared.

Comment: That's correct. Since 5.0 this option triggers the use of the NoTitleBar theme.

Answer (score 1):

From the code [TabGroupProxy](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/TabGroupProxy.java) this error log occur in method `windowCreated` when`activity.getSupportActionBar()` is returning `null`. Check the code

```
    if (activity.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        view = new TiUIActionBarTabGroup(this, activity, savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "ActionBar not available for TabGroup");
        return;
    }
```

> This could happen if your use a theme for your activity with *NoTitleBar* for example `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar`

For more info look [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19695)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess that is a clue but I still don't understand what that means in terms of my app and what I need to do...